# Linear model (lm) on distance matrix is not working on R 4.1.0

Tags: model, distance, lm

I had some code that computed a linear model between two distance matrices to obtain a slope estimate for `abline()`.
In this case, `Dgen` is a pairwise matrix of genetic distances, while `Dgeo` is a pairwise triangular matrix of Euclidean distances. Before upgrading to R 4.1.0, the linear model ran perfectly, and now it produces the following error:

```
model <- lm(Dgen~Dgeo)
Error in xj[i, , drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Did something change in R 4.1.0 that I'm unaware?  I checked the *what's new* on CRAN and didn't see anything
that mentioned `lm()`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it by changing lm(Dgen~Dgeo) to lm(as.numeric(Dgen)~as.numeric(Dgeo)).